# DSL in Drools spreadsheet

Tags: spreadsheet, drools, dsl

I know you can define your own DSL in Drools to be used in DRL.
Is it also possible to define the DSL in a Drools spreadsheet, so I can use it in the spreadsheet? If not, how can I use/integrate a DSL in my Drools spreadsheet?

Thanks!

C YA - Nekro

Comment: +1 for the question. Also offered a 50 rep bounty on it as I recently got interested in using DSL with Drools.

Comment: No takers on this. Will have to give it a try. Unfortunately I don't have time at the moment, but will keep this in mind.

Comment: I played a bit with this but unfortunately I didn't found a solution.. I created a DSL file, compiled it and added it to the spreadsheet compiler but that didn't work.. perhaps I am doing something wrong.. I hope there will be a solution in the future or this feature will be added to Drools